# Very slow WiFi speed

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I recently bought a TP-Link WR841N v10.

In general it is working fine, but the WiFi speed never goes above 840kbps. With Ethernet it can reach speeds as high as 10-20 Mbps. However the WiFi seems to be capped at 840 kbps.

Is this expected? While I do understand that speeds can be slower at 2.4GHz, I still think that the speed is unnaturally low. I have WPA2-PSK authentication,
channel width 20MHz at bgn mixed mode, and WMM activated.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed? And is the encryption AES, TKIP, or both?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz windows task manager, also my android hone and tablet shows the spee. I can easily stream 1080p from youtube via ethernet, but on wifi it is more at 360p. Any file downloads are also much slower over wifi. Chrome and Firefox shows download speed. 
Encryption is AES.

Comment: @Crazy-Fool Can you be more specific about precisely how you are measuring the speed? You have to move data somehow in order to have something whose speed you can measure, right? If you just look at the speed of the data without specifically trying to move any data, you'll get the speed of nothing in particular.

Comment: Same router here: http://superuser.com/questions/866934/very-slow-wi-fi-download-speeds-using-a-tp-link-wr841n-1-10th-of-full-ethernet . Also suggest not disabling WMM.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Initially i tried wifi my streaming a video from youtube. Over the wifi i can never stream at any resolution avove 360p. But plugin the ethernet cable it immediategoes up to 720-1080p as it used to be without any router.

Comment: @Papa In that question the user is having a speed of ~50Mbps. My router is not going anywhere more than 1Mbps.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your network setup? Is there any other router in your network? What is the WR841N connected to? What Wifi hardware does the computer you are testing with have? What channel are you using? What kind of environment are you in (dense, sparse)? How far is the computer from the router?

Comment: Yeah, but there are some avenues to pursue like installing custom firmware. Have you tried resetting to factory defaults? Latest firmware? Static IP?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have a direct cable going to my router. It is a home network. No other wifi router in my flat but may be another one in the nearby flat and some others above or below. Laptop has RTL8723BE Wi-Fi card. And my tablet and phone has wifi b/g/n/ac support, but i do not know the model number of the chip inside. Router and all deviced tested in same room without any wall in between.

Comment: Also before 1 updated to windows 10, I used my laptop i hotspot mode and then the wifi speed used to go up to 10Mbps easily.

Comment: @Papa I got the router yesterday only. Don't know about third party firmwares though. I think the default firmware should be the latest version.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin That's terrible advice. 802.11n and 802.11ac require WMM. If you disable it, standards-compliant clients will drop to 802.11a/g rates (54Mbps max).